# use of tag <sec:authorize> in the jsp pages displaying an error in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

In my spring project, I recently added to my jsp pages this tag:

```
        <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_usuario')">
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="${alteracao}/'+item.id+'">Editar</button>');
        </sec:authorize>

        <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_usuario')">
            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="${remocao}/'+item.id+'">Remover</button>');
        </sec:authorize>
```

to allow me controll what is displayed to user. But the eclipse is displaying an error related to this tags (they are marked with a red underline), which don't prevent the project be built. When I run the project and open the page, the elment inside tag isn't displayed, despite the user had the permission.

Anyone knos what's wrong here?

ps.: the complete code for this page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="../../include/include.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Lista de usu&aacute;rios</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:url value="/usuario/cadastra" var="cadastro"/>
<c:url value="/usuario/altera" var="alteracao"/>
<c:url value="/usuario/remove" var="remocao"/>
<c:url value="/permissao/altera" var="permissao"/>

<p>
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_usuario')">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link link" data-action="${cadastro}">
        cadastrar novo usu&aacute;rio
    </button>
</sec:authorize>
</p>

<table class="bordered">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>        
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Sobrenome</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
        <th>#</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="content">
    </tbody>

</table>

<c:url value="/usuario/listagem.json" var="lista"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "<c:out value="${lista}"/>";
    $.get(url, function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.usuario, function(index, item){
            var row = $('<tr id=user'+item.id+'>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.id+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.login+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.pnome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.unome+'</td>');
            row.append('<td>'+item.email+'</td>');

            var col = $('<td>');

            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_usuario')">
                col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="${alteracao}/'+item.id+'">Editar</button>');
            </sec:authorize>

            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_usuario')">
                col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="${remocao}/'+item.id+'">Remover</button>');
            </sec:authorize>


            col.append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary link" data-action="${permissao}/'+item.id+'">Permiss&otilde;es</button>');
            row.append(col);

            $('tbody.content').append(row);
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have `<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>` in your jsp? ([http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#declaring-the-taglib](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#declaring-the-taglib))

Comment: yes. it's inside the file include.jsp, included on the page I display above.

Comment: How do you configure your `<expression-handler>` within `<http>` and `permissionEvaluator` property? Can you share your spring security configuration?

Comment: Is 'user' defined for the page context?  Have you tried putting a break point in your permissionEvaluator to see what values are coming in from the tag permission call?

Comment: I guess 'user' is defined, since I use this same structure for secure the methods from my controller / service classes. When I execute the view, the error `Jun 04, 2014 7:34:20 PM org.springframework.security.access.expression.DenyAllPermissionEvaluator hasPermission
/ Advertência: Denying user klebermo permission 'cadastra_usuario' on object null` is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PermissionEvaluator implementation is not being called when using `<sec:authorize  access="hasPermission(...)">` according to the error message(`DenyAllPermissionEvaluator` is a Spring Security's default implementation).

Try the following setting in your Spring Security configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true" ...>
  <expression-handler ref="webExpressionHandler"/>
  ...
</http>

<beans:bean id="webExpressionHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
  <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="your.PermissionEvaluator" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My spring configuration is based on java classes. Do you  know where I can find information to do the same with this approach?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974926/how-configure-the-spring-security-to-allow-the-use-for-haspermission-in-the-jsp) question may help you to configure PermissionEvaluator using Java config . I got this information from spring [forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/97058-haspermission-in-sec-authorize) and the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java).